# Conversion between timestamp and dates in C++

Tags: c++

In my program I have an unsigned long long int (called unixutc) that stores a unix timestamp (epoch:1970). What I want to do is calculate the unsigned long long int that corresponds with the same date/time except in another, given year (called inyear, which is a void*, entered as unsigned int*).

What I've cooked up:

```
time_t utc = app->unixutc;
tm* convutc = new tm();
gmtime_s(convutc, &utc);

if (*(unsigned int*)inyear < 1970)
{
    convutc->tm_year = 70;
    convutc->tm_mon = 0;
    convutc->tm_mday = 1;
    convutc->tm_hour = 0;
    convutc->tm_min = 0;
    convutc->tm_sec = 0;

    convutc->tm_wday = 0;
    convutc->tm_yday = 0;
}
else
{
    convutc->tm_year = *(unsigned int*)inyear - 1900;
}
app->unixutc = mktime(convutc);
```

This doesn't work at all. If inyear is less then 1970 the mktime returns with -1 (I've no idea why, it shouldn't). If it is greater then ~3000 it returns -1 (which it shouldn't, I'm compiling in VS2013, I checked the headers, mktime returns a time_t, which is a typedef for __time64_t, which is a typedef for __int64 which is a nice, fat 64bit integer, which should hold ~584 billion years of seconds).
Another weird thing is that if inyear is between 1970 and ~3000 it works correctly, except it gives back a time exactly one hour short.

Comment: What are all these pointers for?

Comment: It's just part of my application, I could replace it with a simple unsigned int, I just didn't want to post the code with any changes, in case I might miss something.

Comment: You should construct a testcase. Abstracting away things like those pointers should be one of your first debugging steps: you _want_ to find out whether they are responsible for the problem! Read http://sscce.org

Comment: `tm* convutc = new tm();`  No!

Comment: care to elaborate on that?